# result of one stored procedure to input for Query showing null

Tags: sql-server

I wrote two stored procedures

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPhysicalChildNodesAsString]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Book varchar(50),
    @Vertical varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @results nvarchar(max)
;WITH cte AS 
 (
  SELECT a.BookID, a.ParentBookID, a.BookName
  FROM DimBook a
  WHERE BookName = @Book
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.BookID, a.ParentBookID, a.BookName
  FROM DimBook a JOIN cte c ON a.ParentBookID = c.BookID
  and HighPortfolioID = ( select PortfolioID from portfolioMaster where PortfolioName = @Vertical and PortfolioType='HighPortfolio')
  )
  select @results = coalesce(@results + ',', '')+'''' +  convert(varchar(max),BookName)+''''
  from cte Where Len(BookName) < 20

  select @results as Book

END
```

Above stored Proc returns below string

```
'Physical','Anish Vohra','Sandeep Bajoria','Nirav Desai','Sushil Mohta','Sahil Pasad','G R Poddar','Direct','Sales Broker','Internal Transfer','Sprint','Murji Meghan','Intra Oils & Fats','GGN','GGN1','GGN2','Book1','Book2','Book 3','Book4','Book5','Comglobal','Sunvin','PVOC','Afro Asian'
```

```sql
DECLARE @BooksList varchar(max) 
DECLARE @t table(BookNames varchar(max) )
   INSERT @t(BookNames)
   EXEC @BooksList = GetPhysicalChildNodesAsString 'Physical','Enterprise'
   
   SELECT @BooksList = BookNames FROM @t

   select @BooksList as 'books'

   select * from DimBook where BookName IN(select @BooksList as 'books') ----> reults only header of table Only. But if pass result string directly like below it is working. can you help me for why above query is not working

   select * from DimBook where BookName IN('Physical','Anish Vohra','Sandeep Bajoria','Nirav Desai','Sushil Mohta','Sahil Pasad','G R Poddar','Direct','Sales Broker','Internal Transfer','Sprint','Murji Meghan','Intra Oils & Fats','GGN','GGN1','GGN2','Book1','Book2','Book 3','Book4','Book5','Comglobal','Sunvin','PVOC','Afro Asian') ----> getting correctly.
```

Comment: I don't follow what you are asking here. It you want to consume the output value from the procedure, you'll need to `INSERT` the data into a table. YOu would likely be better off using an `OUTPUT` parameter if I am honest.

Comment: if i pass the result string in query im getting correct output. But select * from DimBook where BookName IN(select @BooksList as 'books') showing headers only

Comment: Also using the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your data in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.